# Beanshell function gets called before if/else evaluation

Tags: jmeter

I have created 2 BeanShell functions myFoo1 and myFoo2.

The first func should be executed with certain condition and the second function in different condition

The trouble is that in my JSR223Post Processor or BeanPost Processor

```
String code = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
if (code.contains("200") && (vars.get("abc1") != "Howdee")) {
    ${__BeanShell(myFoo1("print this"))}

}
else {
    ${__BeanShell(myFoo2("print this"))}
}
```

The problem is the beanShell functins myFoo1 and myFoo2 get called before the if/else evaluation.

In another words myFoo1 and myFoo2 they both get called one after another and if/else never has any effect, so it looks like Bean function calls are executed before any evaluation. 
How do I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `${__BeanShell(` from the script and call it directly as `myFoo2("print this)`:

```
String code = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode();
if (code.contains("200") && (vars.get("abc1") != "Howdee")) {
    myFoo1("print this);

}
else {
    myFoo2("print this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to call that function unless I have --> ${__BeanShell(    I have tried calling it myFoo1("print this");  I get an error for line before (inline evaluation of code).  Then I also tried  ${__myFoo1("print this")}   I get the same error. I cna only call that function if I use ${__BeanShell  next to it but then I a back to the original issue